# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in node js

Tags: node.js

this is the .sms file . I'm trying to call an resendOTP api but im geeting an error that `.then is undefined`

```
   var aws = require('aws-sdk')

   aws.config.update({
     region: '********',
     accessKeyId: "********",
     secretAccessKey:"*********"
  });

   var sns = new aws.SNS();
    sns.setSMSAttributes({
     attributes: { DefaultSMSType: "Transactional" }
   },
   function (error) {
     if (error) {
      console.log(error);
   }
  });

   function sendSms(phoneNumber, body) {
  // console.log(`Sending SMS. Phone: ${phoneNumber}, body: ${body}`);
    var params = {
      Message: body,
      MessageStructure: 'string',
      PhoneNumber: phoneNumber
    };

sns.publish(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    }
    else {
       // console.log(data);           // successful response
    }
 });
}

module.exports = sendSms
```

`.then` is showing undefined.

```
 exports.resendOTP = async( req, res) => {
   const { id } = req.body;
   const user = await  User.findOne({ _id : id })
   if (!user) {
      res.status(200).send({
         message: "User was not found"
      });
   }
  else {
    var OTP = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
    var encryptOTP = encrypt(OTP.toString());
    var body = 'Hi, '+OTP+' is your One Time Password.';
  sendSms(user.countryCode+user.phoneNumber, body).then(message => {
    if (message) {
    res.status(200).send({
      message: "Updated Sucessfully"
    });
    }
  }) 
}
```

}

Comment: If you don't understand where the problem is, then i strongly recommend you to learn the basics of javascript. Specialy Promises since `then` function is part of it. Hint: `sendSms` does not return anything. `var value = sendSms(...)` now value is undefined since sendSms did not retuned anything. so it's like calling `(undefined).then()`

Comment: i understand , but what i'm doing wrong here . why `sendSms` is getting undefined

Comment: In order for a function to return something you need to use a `return` keyword. So if you want to use smsSend as if it was a Promise(assuming because you use `then`) then it needsto return a Promise.

Comment: i used return keyword `TypeError: sendSms is not a function` i got this error message